# Show that $f(z) = \frac{\sinh (\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have to show that $f(z) = \frac{\sinh (\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$. My attempt is the following:

1. Let $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$, where $g(z) = \sinh (\sqrt z)$ and $h(z) = \sqrt z$.
2. Show that $h(z) =  \sqrt z$ is holomorphic by showing that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.
3. Show that $g(z) = \sinh \sqrt z$ is holomorphic by showing that the C-R equations hold.

For the 2. step, altough a bit tedious, I managed to show that $\sqrt z$ satisfies the C-R equations. My question is, if I write $g(z) = \sinh \sqrt z = \frac{e^{\sqrt z} - e^{- \sqrt z}}{2}$ and make the substitution $\sqrt z = w = a + ib$, can I show that the C-R equations hold for $\sinh \sqrt z$?

Or, formulated differently, if a function has an another function which is holomorphic as it's argument, can I show the holomorphicity of this function by just making a substitution?

Comment: $\sqrt{z}$ is not holomorphic in $\Bbb C$, so you need a different approach.

Comment: @jjagmath isn't a function holomorphic if I can show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold?

Comment: Try writing the function as a power series.

Comment: @syphracos You need it also to be differentiable in the sense of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and satisfy the C-R equations. $\sqrt{z}$ is not even continuous when considered as a map on the entire complex plane (this is since $\log(z)$ is not continuous as a function on the entire complex plane)

Comment: $\frac{\sinh(w)}{w}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{w^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$ Now letting $w=\sqrt z$, we see that $w^{2n}=z^n$ and we have a Taylor series for $\frac{\sinh(\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$

Comment: thanks to all the comments!
But what does it say that I have the Taylor series for the function? Does it from there follow that the function is holomorphic?

Comment: @GBA $\sqrt z$ is not continuous, but $(\sqrt{z})^2$ is most certainly continuous.  And for any holomorphic function $f(z)$ that is even, $f(\sqrt z)$ is also holomorphic.  There is no required branch cut.

Comment: @GBA And what on earth is your point?   $\frac{\sinh(z)}{z}$ is even.

Comment: To answer syphracos: both in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $\mathbb{C}$, an analytic function (i.e. function that can be written as some convergent power series locally around every point of an open set) is always infinitely differentiable (and the power series in question was (were?) actually its Taylor series), and so in particular it's differentiable, aka holomorphic in the case of $\mathbb{C}$. (In $\mathbb{C}$ only, the converse will hold, being holomorphic implies being analytic, but I don't know if you've seen that yet)

Comment: @BrunoB thanks! So I just have to get from the function $\frac{\sinh \sqrt z}{\sqrt z}$ to the power series and show that by using the substitution I get the Taylor series for this function?

Comment: Yes (unless the initial exercise/the person behind it explicitly wanted you to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations for some reason?)

Comment: @BrunoB do You have a tip on how to get to the power series? 
and no, there is no explicit requierment for using the C-R equations

Comment: Well, Mark Viola did exactly that above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic and even (i.e., $f(-z)=f(z)$).  Then $f(\sqrt z)$ is holomorphic.

To see this, we can cut the plane from $0$ to the point at infinity.  On opposite sides of the branch cut, $\sqrt{z}$ changes sign.  For example, suppose we cut the plane along the positive real axis such that on the upper part of the branch cut $\sqrt {1+i0^+}=1$.  Then on the lower part, we see that we have$\sqrt{1+i0^-}=-1=-\sqrt {1+i0^+}$.

For an even function, $f(\sqrt{z})=f(-\sqrt z)$ and $f$ is continuous across the branch cut.  Moreover, inasmuch as $f(z)$ is even and holomorphic function, it has a Taylor series representation

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^{2n}$$

Hence, $f(\sqrt{z})$ also has a Taylor series representation

$$f(\sqrt z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^{n}$$

and we see that $f(\sqrt z)$ is holomorphic.   Hence,  inasmuch as $\frac{\sinh(z)}{z}$ is even and holomorphic, so is $\frac{\sinh(\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$

Comment: thanks for the answer Mark! 
If I understand it correctly, I can prove it either like You wrote it in the answer or as You wrote it in the comment above by writing the function as a power series. Am I correct?
If so, can You maybe show the step from the function to the power series that You mentioned above?  Because I don't quite get it how You get the power series

Comment: @syphracos You're welcome.  My pleasure.  
Remember that the terms of the Taylor series around $0$ for $f(z)$ are $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.  You know how to differentiate $\sinh(w)$ and evaluate the derivatives at $w=0$, right?  Find that Taylor series and then divide by $w$.  Now let $w=\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: Alternatively, the power series for $\cos$, $\cosh$, $\sin$ and $\sinh$ can all be obtained from the power series of $\exp$ taken at $\pm z$ or $\pm iz$.

Comment: @BrunoB Yes, that is another way forward.  ;-)

Comment: (+1) Always a pleasure to read you solutions.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Hello my friend!  How are you?  And thank you for the up vote.  Much appreciative.